# Capacitor constant power charge, constant current discharge curve

Tags: capacitor, math, calculus

I have an (ideal) capacitor that is simultaneously being charged through a DC/DC boost converter (assumed constant power \$P_{in}\$) and discharged through a linear regulator (assumed constant current \$I_{out}\$).
I would like to analytically find the relation between time \$t\$ and the energy stored on the capacitor \$E(t)\$.

I tried to approach it through the energy/power equation with capacitor voltage \$v_c\$:

\$E(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\big[P_{in}-v_c(\tau)\cdot I_{out}\big] \, d\tau + E(0)\$

Clearly, \$v_c(t)\$ is not independent of \$E\$ and I'm currently lacking the right approach to solving this integral.
Obviously the same thing happens when writing the equation in terms of voltage.

Would highly appreciate a solution or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: I'm afraid not.. I guess most of what you said has already been integrated in the equation in my question, right? I am able to calculate either constant power charge or constant current discharge - no problem at all. But I'm having troubles to connect both of them. Are you suggesting a different approach than what I proposed?

Comment: If Iout is constant and duty cycle is 50% the input current must be at least double on average

Comment: @mkeith yes, it is simultaneous. Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll add it in the main question.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What exactly do you mean with duty cycle? Consider the boost converter as constant power source and the linear regulator as constant current sink. There's no duty cycling of either of the two. I'm less interested in if it's sustainable, but in questions like: How long is the time until I reach energy X, when starting with energy Y. Or what's my energy level after time X.

Comment: I don't think my comments are helpful except to helping me finally understand the question so I am going to delete them. Apologize for the unproductive time.

Comment: Peter . yes it was a hypothetical remark. Boost normally uses fixed pulse widths in PFM mode but I was just suggesting the conservation of energy ideal.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I am sure you can get a reasonable approximation using numerical methods in a spreadsheet.

Comment: You're right and I'm working with something similar right now. But I work in academia and it would be nice to be able to provide a concise formula together with any results.